# Do I need to use unique_ptr over std::function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, std-function

I have a factory returning a function for data processing

```
class Factory {
    function<void(Data&)> build();
}
```

Now I am struggling whether the return type should be `function<void(Data&)>` or `unique_ptr<function<void(Data&)>>`. In other words, how heavy is the std function, is it okay to copy it around or is it better to manage it using a smart pointer?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294620/what-is-the-best-smart-pointer-return-type-for-a-factory-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` uses some form of *type erasure*, therefore, it itself shouldn't be too big. For instance, in my experiment with GCC and libstdc++, all instances of `std::function` I tried had 32 bytes: [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MA7z8x). Therefore, *moving* `std::function` objects should be relatively cheap (*copying* might be a different thing).

Anyway, `std::unique_ptr` is still smaller (typically a size of a raw pointer), therefore, it will be moved faster at an assembly level. Whether it does matter is a matter of profiling.

Comment: don't forget that using `unique_ptr` adds yet another level of indirection. Also more cache trashing.

Comment: @bolov Don't understand what do you mean. `unique_ptr` is typically implemented as a class with a single raw-pointer member variable that points directly to the managed object. Where is any indirection?

Comment: when you call the function you have one extra indirection via the pointer.